# Relationship between momentum and angle in ballistic pendulum

Tags: mass, momentum, velocity, projectile

Using the ballistic pendulum apparatus, I am going to estimate the velocity of the ball to get up to 45°. I have the mass of the ball, and mass of the pendulum. I would really want to substitute it into the equation:

$$ M_\text{ball} \times V_\text{ball} = (M_\text{ball} + M_\text{pendulum}) \times V_\text{pendulum} $$

But I don't know the velocity of the pendulum.

Is there any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the ball comes in from the left, hits the pendulum and makes it rotate by 45° as you say in your question:

[image: Ballistic pendulum]

As the pendulum rotates the bob moves upwards, and after rotating by 45° it will have moved upwards by a distance $h$ that you can calculate from the geometry. This means the potential energy of the bob+ball has increased by:

$$ \Delta U = (M_\text{ball} + M_\text{pendulum})gh $$

This change in the potential energy must have come from the kinetic energy of the bob+ball immediately after the impact, and that must have come from the initial kinetic energy of the ball. So we have:

$$ (M_\text{ball} + M_\text{pendulum})gh = \tfrac{1}{2}(M_\text{ball} + M_\text{pendulum}) V_\text{pendulum}^2 = \tfrac{1}{2}M_\text{ball} V_\text{ball}^2 $$

From this you can calculate $V_\text{pendulum}$ and $V_\text{ball}$.

Comment: But I am supposed to calculate the velocity of the ball using Mb, Mp, and Vp. Is there another method to calculate the Vp?

Comment: I am investigating on how momentum of Vb effect the angle released.